# Matlab: deciding whether a value is between the column entries of a nx2 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am writing a Matlab Tool and certain processes have to be automated.

I am running a for loop, in which some decisions need to be made. Here is a piece of my code:

```
    DecisionMatrix = [0.2 0.4; 0.5 0.7];

        Beta =0:pi/20:pi;
        Span_Loc = 0.5*(1-cos(Beta))';  

        for i=1:length(Span_Loc)
          Position = Span(i)

    % Check Clean of High Lift
    if Position >=  DecisionMatrix(1,1) && Position <=  DecisionMatrix(1,2)

% HighLift run  code here

    elseif Position >=  DecisionMatrix(2,1) && Position <=    DecisionMatrix(2,2)



    else

% Clean run code here
    end

        end
```

Herein, `DecisionMatrix` is a variable size matrix which is nx2 always. What I want to do is to determine when the value of `Position` is between the entries of  any row of `DecisionMatrix`. This should be easy when  `DecisionMatrix`  is a constant matrix (as shown above). However, this matrix has a variable number of rows.

Hence, how would you do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine when the value of `Position` (scalar) is between the entries of any row of `DecisionMatrix` (2-column matrix):

```
result = any(Position>=DecisionMatrix(:,1) & Position<=DecisionMatrix(:,2));
```

The above gives a *`logical` result* (`true` or `false`). If you need to know the *indices of the rows* that fulfill the condition:

```
result = find(Position>=DecisionMatrix(:,1) & Position<=DecisionMatrix(:,2));
```

Comment: Thanks this works!  I actually only needed the  logical  results but thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your code by introducing another loop and coming out of it when you find the required row.

```
DecisionMatrix = [0.2 0.4; 0.5 0.7];
Beta =0:pi/20:pi;
Span_Loc = 0.5*(1-cos(Beta))';

for p=1:length(Span_Loc)
    Position = Span(p);
    for q=1:n
        if Position >=  DecisionMatrix(q,1) && Position <=  DecisionMatrix(q,2)
            %do what you want when the condition is true
            break
        end
    end
end
```